# Get the form data on load submit

Tags: javascript, post

**I want the form data that was submitted on page load via POST method**

*Here is my code*

```
<body onload="document.forms["Form1"].submit()">
    <form id="Form1" method="POST" action="page2.aspx">
       <input type="hidden" name="Status" value="success">
       <input type="hidden" name="Date" value="05/05/2016">
    </form>    
</body>
```

**What I want is to get the form data when ever this page is loaded**

*What I tried*

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function () {
    var status, date;var str = '';
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'status') {
            status= inputs[i];
        }
        else if (inputs[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'date') {
            date= inputs[i];
        }
    }//for close

    if (status != null) {
        str += status.value;
    }
    else if (date != null) {
        str += date.value;
    }
}//func close
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your code inside `window.onload` evnet.

Try this

```js
window.onload = function() {    
      var str = '';
      var status, date;
      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'status') {
         status= inputs[i];
        }
        else if (inputs[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'date') {         
         date= inputs[i];
        }
      }//for close

      if (status != null) {
       str += status.value;
      }      
      if (date != null) {       
       str += date.value;
      }

      alert(str);
    };
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <body onload="document.forms["Form1"].submit()">

<form id="Form1" method="POST" action="page2.aspx">

<input type="hidden" name="Status" value="success">
<input type="hidden" name="Date" value="05/05/2016">

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Jitendra Tiwari Sir I can't change the HTML code. I can only modify the javascript.

Comment: don't worry :) leave HTML code as it is. see my updated answer

Comment: don't call anyone to SIR here :)

Comment: can I run the code of java script in console and get the desired output.

Comment: can you do the same thing in android with webView?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you submitting the form while user has not even filled the form **body onload** !
If you are allowed to use *Jquery* it will do your task easy

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function () {
$(this).serializeArray();
}//func close
```

Please have a look at this [link for details](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Here is a small demonstration

```js
$(document).ready(
   function() {
     $("#Form1").on('submit', function() {
       var data = $(this).serializeArray()
       console.log(data);
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

         document.body.innerHTML += 'Key: '+data[i].name +' and Value: '+ data[i].value + '</br>';
       }

       return false;
     });

     $("#Form1").submit();
   }
 )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Form1" method="POST" action="page2.aspx">

  <input type="hidden" name="Status" value="success">
  <input type="hidden" name="Date" value="05/05/2016">

</form>
```

Comment: Sir the form is pre filled and it has to be submitted on page load. The user will not fill the form.

Comment: no problem it depends on your use :) . Just tell me if serializing it in array using jquery sorts out your problem or not

Comment: let me see please.

Comment: i have added a demo please see the snippet and check if it works as per your requirements

Comment: Ok your code is working perfectly..now the second stage of my task is to do the same thing in android webView.... Any one help me please

Comment: If it helped you! please give some credit by upvoting or marking as answer to help others know the solution :) thanks!

Comment: and for the cause of WebView, please add a question but before this ! do some hard research

Comment: Its not letting me to up vote because of reputation.

Comment: Please read [this forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to follow the rules as chit chat is not allowed. Sorry but it is necessary :) . Best of luck for your webview problem